# Comparing two lists similar to startswith

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list, startswith

I'm trying to write simple logic that will look for words in one list that start with words from other list. For example:

```
a = ["let","test","g"]
b = ["letter", "testing","good","egg","protest"]
```

should return: `letter, testing, good`.

I have dabbled with `.startswith()` but it seems to be unable to use entire list for searching. Also tried with:

```
if any(i in a for i in b):
```

but I am unable to get any results with it.

Answer (score 9):

`str.startswith()` accepts a tuple:

```
>>> a = ["let","test","g"]
>>> b = ["letter", "testing","good","egg","protest"]
>>> a = tuple(a)
>>> [item for item in b if item.startswith(a)]
['letter', 'testing', 'good']
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. Yes, I was able to simply go with .startswith and it works.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with list comprehension:

```
>>> [y for x in a for y in b if y.startswith(x)]
['letter', 'testing', 'good']
```

You need to iterate over both of the lists, and then check if the elements from the list `a` are the start of the objects in list `b`.

If you just need it for conditional testing, you better off with generators. This will stop on the first match in the list:

```
>>> gen_exp = (y for x in a for y in b if y.startswith(x))
>>> if any(gen_exp):
        __ your logic here __
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the first element in `b` that starts with some string, you can use `next`.

```
word = next(bword for bword in b if bword.startswith(aword))
```

In case there is no such word in `b`, you can supply a default value

```
word = next((bword for bword in b if bword.startswith(aword)), None)
```

To apply to that to each element of `a`, you could use a list comprehension.

```
words = [next((bword for bword in b if bword.startswith(aword)), None) for aword in a]
```

This produces:

```
['letter', 'testing', 'good']
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using the `itertools` module for such cases:

```py
>>> [value for (start, value) in itertools.product(a,b) if value.startswith(start)]
['letter', 'testing', 'good']
```